# Writing to a text File in C#

Tags: c#

Hi i am trying to write to a text file in C# console but the text file needs to include " i can not find anything that includes these when writing to a text file. The error i get is too many characters in character literal.

I have tried the following as well

```
StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter("Test.csproj");

File.Write('<Project ToolsVersion= "14.0"DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003>"');
```

I can not figure out what i am doing wrong.

this what needs to be written in the text file

```
<Project ToolsVersion= "14.0"DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003>"
```

Comment: try fewer and simpler words first, then long ones.

Comment: C# is not like python where you can interchangeably use `'...'` and `"..."` to define strings. The former is for a _single character_ (data type `char`). The latter is for strings

Comment: i uploaded a image to help

Comment: Please don't upload screenshots of text. Instead, paste your text here and [format](/help/formatting) it appropriately, e.g. using a code block

Comment: ok sorry i didnt know i wasnt allowed too

Comment: That string you want to write is **WRONG**. It will lead to invalid Xml. The final closing angle bracket (`>`) needs to be _after_ completing the xmlns attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in C# must be surrounded with double quotes, not single quotes, and you can **escape them with a back-slash (\) character.**

```
File.Write("<Project ToolsVersion=\"14.0\" ... ");
```

Single quotes in C# are *only for single characters*, which is why the error complains about too many characters in a *character* literal.

This is also missing whitespace between `"14.0"` and `DefaultTargets`, and misplaces the final angle bracket. The exact string you want to write almost certainly looks like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

But it seems strange to me that someone new to the language is already trying to build MS Build files programmatically, and there are other tools in the platform for dealing with Xml. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: if i add double quotes it wont write the double quotes in the file this is what needs to write exactly to the text file <Project ToolsVersion= "14.0"DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003>"

Comment: Look more closely at my example. Also, you're missing whitespace between `"14.0"` and `DefaultTargets`.

Comment: i uploaded a photo

Comment: Nope. Photos are not good for that. Look at my sample. It shows you how to include double quotes inside a string literal.

Comment: @JamesClark if you want to include " in a string you use back-slash \ like `\"` so if you write `"I said, \" This sample is correct \""` C# will accept it